# How to create a to string?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, outlook

I am trying to create an Outlook email for multiple recipients.

I have two sheets 1 and 2.

I want the code in sheet 1 column B to look into Sheet 2 column A and pick up all the email addresses matched the codes and create an email with list recipients in tostring and do repeat task for second code till its empty.

Also attach files corresponding to that code in column c in sheet 1.

Its in the Sheet 2 column B

I have clients' names in sheet 1 column B and there is corresponding names in sheet 2 Column A and email addresses in Column B.

I created below code. How do I create a to string in VBA?

```vb
Sub GenerateEmail()
i = 2 ' selects row 2 ,since row 1 ,i am keeping for titles
Dim wbBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim doText As DataObject
Dim wsSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim x As Variant
Dim myemail As String
Dim myrange As Range
Dim n As Range
Dim sm2 As Range

Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
Set sm2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("A2:A1000")
Set sm1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("B2:B1000")

Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, "B").Value = ""

    EmailTo = tostring

    BCC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("J3").Value
    Subj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("J4").Value
    Path = "N:\Folder 1\Folder 2\Folder 3\Folder 3\Result\"
    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, 3)
    SM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, 2)

    x = Replace(Range("Content1").Value, "<PROJECTION DATE1>", Format(Range("GenerationMonth").Value, "mmmm"))
    x = x & Replace(Range("Content2").Value, "<PROJECTION DATE2>", Format(Range("GenerationMonth").Value, "mmmm-yyyy"))
    x = x & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 3").Range("Content3").Value
    Msg = x

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Preparing email..."
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Variables for MS Outlook.
    'Variables for MS Outlook.

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "Cleint1@Hotmail.com"
        .To = EmailTo
        .BCC = "Cleint1@Hotmail.com"
        .Subject = "This is my subject" & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm yyyy")
         .Attachments.Add Path & FileName
        .Display
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
        .Body = Msg
        'send
    End With
    i = i + 1
    Set doText = Nothing
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Loop

Cells(7, "J").Value = "Outlook msg count =" & i - 1

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Workbooks(MyFile).Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi its in column B,  sheet 2 I have clients names in sheet 1 column B and there is corresponding names in sheet 2 Column A and Email addresses in Column B. Your promptly reply will be much appreciated Thank you

Comment: Hi Dave, I have deleted the post..I am new to this site. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to start your loop and get the "To:" variable.

I comment out most of the code because I don't have your workbook and the code would not work in my situation.

```
Sub DoItEmail()


'Dim doText As DataObject
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim myemail As String
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim n As Range
    Dim sm2 As Range

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    '==================================================================
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim Rws2 As Long, Rng2 As Range, b As Range, SndTo As String

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    With sh
        Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("A2:A" & Rws)
    End With
    With ws
        Rws2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng2 = .Range("C2:C" & Rws2)
    End With

    For Each c In Rng.Cells
        For Each b In Rng2.Cells
            If b = c Then
                SndTo = b.Offset(0, 1)    'this would be your "to:" variable
                'MsgBox SndTo & " is the To: variable"

                'EmailTo = tostring

                BCC = sh.Range("J3").Value
                Subj = sh.Range("J4").Value
                'Path = "N:\Folder 1\Folder 2\Folder 3\Folder 3\Result\"
                'FileName = sh.Cells(i, 3)
                'SM = sh.Cells(i, 2)


                '            x = Replace(Range("Content1").Value, "<PROJECTION DATE1>", Format(Range("GenerationMonth").Value, "mmmm"))
                '            x = x & Replace(Range("Content2").Value, "<PROJECTION DATE2>", Format(Range("GenerationMonth").Value, "mmmm-yyyy"))
                '            x = x & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 3").Range("Content3").Value
                '            Msg = x



                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                'Application.StatusBar = "Preparing email..."
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False


                'Variables for MS Outlook.
                'Variables for MS Outlook.



                Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                With OutMail
                    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "Cleint1@Hotmail.com"
                    .To = SndTo
                    .BCC = "Cleint1@Hotmail.com"
                    .Subject = "This is my subject: " & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm yyyy")
                    '.Attachments.Add Path & FileName
                    .Display
                    .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
                    .Body = Msg
                    'send
                End With
                i = i + 1
                Set doText = Nothing
                Application.CutCopyMode = False



                Cells(7, "J").Value = "Outlook msg count =" & i

                Set OutMail = Nothing
                Set OutApp = Nothing

                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                'Workbooks(MyFile).Close
            End If

        Next b
    Next c
    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dave,
Thank you for your assistance.
I tried to use the code you gave but doesn’t give any result I am looking for. Do you know where I can upload the excel book so that we are in same page?
Thank you

Comment: Here you go the link to file. Thanks Basically I want each email is created with multiple recipients of same code in to string in outlook with attachments added. Each attachments name starts with short name. Then it loops to second short name  repeat the task and so on

Comment: I used the above code you provided, it only generates emails with first few email with same email ids. It doesn't not generate any other email or attachments.

Comment: Its creating same email repetitively with same email addresses and no attachments are attached also ?

Comment: I have to create 1 email from sheet 1 Column "Name" with   "Client 1" then followed by another email with "Client 2". The attachments are saved in one location. All the files starts with the short name that should attached corresponding to Client name. So for example when first email is generated from sheet 1 column "A" Column with name "Client 1" it should pick up all the email addresses that corresponds with same name in sheet 2 and add attachment...the attachment name starts with short name in sheet 1 column “B”. Email 2 will be all email ids with "client 2" name and 1 attachments

Comment: Only 1 email should be generated for each name from sheet 1 column "A" or Column "B"

Comment: You have enough that will get you the e-mail address, just use the offset to get the file names and other info from that row. I was just showing you how to loop through the ranges and get the email addresses, not do the entire code.